# Как в vs code запускать скрипты python с аргументами командной строки?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Хотелось бы в *vs code* запускать скрипты с аргументами используя что-то вроде того что есть в pycharm:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Т.е. написать какие то постоянные аргументы и постоянно запускать скрипт с ними. Через командную строку запускать и менять их при случае не так удобно. Так вот, как сделать подобное в VS CODE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Открываете папку с файлом, который собираетесь запускать (меню `File -> Open folder`), слева в навигаторе (Explorer) выбираете нужный файл. Дальше идете в меню `Run -> Add configuration` (т.е. добавить конфигурацию запуска), выбираете "Python file" (т.е. запуск обычного файла) или другой нужный вариант (например debug для запуска с в режиме отладки). После этого в подпапке `.vscode` создается файл `launch.json` примерно такого содержания:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Текущий файл",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        }
    ]
}
```

В разделе "configurations" добавляете ключ "args", в нем в списке перечисляете передаваемые аргументы, например:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Текущий файл",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "args": ["first", "second", "third"]
        }
    ]
}
```

`name` тоже можно поменять на то которое вам нужно.

Сохраняете файл. После этого в панели слева переходите в раздел Run, выбираете сверху конфигурацию с тем именем, которое вы прописали в name, жмете зеленый треугольник **слева от названия выбранной конфигурации** (не справа сверху от открытого файла) - файл запускается с нужным набором параметром.

Пример программы:

```
import sys

print(*sys.argv)
```

Результат (вывод программы обведен красным):

[image: Скриншот]

Comment: По какой то причине при print(sys.argv) не выводит аргументы прописанные json'е

Comment: @james, дополнил, там два зеленых треугольника, нужно жать конкретно на треугольник рядом с названием выбранной конфигурации)

Comment: Видимо я что-то делаю не так, но мне по прежнему не помогает.

Answer (score 0):

```
"name": "Python: Current File with my args",
"type": "python",
"request": "launch",
"program": "${file}",
"args": ["**************"],
"console": "integratedTerminal"
```

или как в ответе выше только пропустили запятую после "],

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

> > > @james, дополнил, там два зеленых треугольника, нужно жать конкретно на треугольник рядом с названием выбранной конфигурации) –
> > > insolor
> > > 15 апр 2020 в 7:21

[image: debug 1-2]
есть две кнопки, дебага... та, что номер 2 на рисунке, все еще поддерживает выбор конфигурации и указание параметров в файле Json
первая - после обновления сломалась... откат на старую версию уже не помог.
возможно ее тоже можно как-то настроить но у меня не получилось.